# with out host name details(for sending E-mail) how to upload in to appspot

Tags: google-app-engine

With the help of  Google App Engine Api,  I have developed send Email in my application **http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail.html**

It was executing fine with no errors, status code is 200 its showing, But I am not able to seen the E-mail (which I mentioned in code)

But in my Development server with help of 
**dev_appserver.py --smtp_host=smtp.example.com --smtp_port=25 \
    --smtp_user=ajohnson --smtp_password=k1tt3ns myapp**
I can able to execute, while upload into appspot.com, we can't able to mentioned details of host name... etc. details.

any one tell me how can solve my issue , where I can mention my host details (other than development server) while upload the code into appspot.com,

In my development server I have used host has gmail and user name and password is my gmail account details

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to supply hostname details - email on App Engine uses the email API, which uses Google's own mail servers.